# Best way to check if UITableViewCell is completely visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, visible

I have a UITableView with cells of different heights and I need to know when they are **completely** visible or not.

At the moment I am looping through each cell in the list of visible cells to check if it is completely visible every time the view is scrolled . Is this the best approach?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;    
    NSArray* cells = myTableView.visibleCells;

    for (MyCustomUITableViewCell* cell in cells) {

        if (cell.frame.origin.y > offset.y &&
            cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height < offset.y + bounds.size.height) {

            [cell notifyCompletelyVisible];
        }
        else {

            [cell notifyNotCompletelyVisible];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Please note that *- (NSArray *)visibleCells* returns visible cells which are both completely visible and partly visible.

**Edit 2:**

This is the revised code after combining solutions from both *lnafziger* and *Vadim Yelagin*:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    NSArray* cells = myTableView.visibleCells;
    NSArray* indexPaths = myTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows;

    NSUInteger cellCount = [cells count];

    if (cellCount == 0) return;

    // Check the visibility of the first cell
    [self checkVisibilityOfCell:[cells objectAtIndex:0] forIndexPath:[indexPaths objectAtIndex:0]];

    if (cellCount == 1) return;

    // Check the visibility of the last cell
    [self checkVisibilityOfCell:[cells lastObject] forIndexPath:[indexPaths lastObject]];

    if (cellCount == 2) return;

    // All of the rest of the cells are visible: Loop through the 2nd through n-1 cells
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < cellCount - 1; i++)
        [[cells objectAtIndex:i] notifyCellVisibleWithIsCompletelyVisible:YES];
}

- (void)checkVisibilityOfCell:(MultiQuestionTableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect cellRect = [myTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellRect = [myTableView convertRect:cellRect toView:myTableView.superview];
    BOOL completelyVisible = CGRectContainsRect(myTableView.frame, cellRect);

    [cell notifyCellVisibleWithIsCompletelyVisible:completelyVisible];
}
```

Comment: This is a GRRRRREAT answer from @matt with an animation to along with it https://stackoverflow.com/a/68109661/4833705

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can get the rect of a cell with [`rectForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForRowAtIndexPath:) method and compare it with tableview's bounds rect using [`CGRectContainsRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsRect) function.

Note that this will not instantiate the cell if it is not visible, and thus will be rather fast.

**Swift**

```
let cellRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
```

**Obj-C**

```
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
BOOL completelyVisible = CGRectContainsRect(tableView.bounds, cellRect);
```

Of course this will not regard the table view being clipped by a superview or obscured by another view.

Comment: On the second thought it can be just `CGRectContainsRect(tableView.bounds, [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])`

Comment: why is that my cellRect's origin.x = 0, origin.y = 0, width = 0, height = 0? although on UI they are not all 0s, I am using auto layout, any ideas?

Comment: Swift 3: `let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath))`

Comment: How would this handle situations where the table view is partially obscured by the keyboard?

Answer (score 65):

I would change it like this:

```
- (void)checkVisibilityOfCell:(MyCustomUITableViewCell *)cell inScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGRect cellRect = [aScrollView convertRect:cell.frame toView:aScrollView.superview];

    if (CGRectContainsRect(aScrollView.frame, cellRect))
        [cell notifyCompletelyVisible];
    else
        [cell notifyNotCompletelyVisible];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView { 
    NSArray* cells = myTableView.visibleCells;

    NSUInteger cellCount = [cells count];
    if (cellCount == 0)
        return;

    // Check the visibility of the first cell
    [self checkVisibilityOfCell:[cells firstObject] inScrollView:aScrollView];
    if (cellCount == 1)
        return;

    // Check the visibility of the last cell
    [self checkVisibilityOfCell:[cells lastObject] inScrollView:aScrollView];
    if (cellCount == 2)
        return;

    // All of the rest of the cells are visible: Loop through the 2nd through n-1 cells
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < cellCount - 1; i++)
        [[cells objectAtIndex:i] notifyCompletelyVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try something like this to see how much percentage is visible:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    [self checkWhichVideoToEnable];
}

-(void)checkWhichVideoToEnable
{
    for(UITableViewCell *cell in [tblMessages visibleCells])
    {
        if([cell isKindOfClass:[VideoMessageCell class]])
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblMessages indexPathForCell:cell];
            CGRect cellRect = [tblMessages rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIView *superview = tblMessages.superview;

            CGRect convertedRect=[tblMessages convertRect:cellRect toView:superview];
            CGRect intersect = CGRectIntersection(tblMessages.frame, convertedRect);
            float visibleHeight = CGRectGetHeight(intersect);

            if(visibleHeight>VIDEO_CELL_SIZE*0.6) // only if 60% of the cell is visible
            {
                // unmute the video if we can see at least half of the cell
                [((VideoMessageCell*)cell) muteVideo:!btnMuteVideos.selected];
            }
            else
            {
                // mute the other video cells that are not visible
                [((VideoMessageCell*)cell) muteVideo:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Catalin I've tried your solution but my tableview gets slowdown. Any way to improve scrolling performence ?

Comment: @RahulVyas sorry but no :( check your inner elements maybe the layout can be optimized a bit as it regards layers/sublayers

Answer (score 7):

If you also want to take the contentInset into account, and don't want to rely on a superview (the table view frame in superview could be something else than 0,0), here's my solution:

```
extension UITableView {

    public var boundsWithoutInset: CGRect {
        var boundsWithoutInset = bounds
        boundsWithoutInset.origin.y += contentInset.top
        boundsWithoutInset.size.height -= contentInset.top + contentInset.bottom
        return boundsWithoutInset
    }

    public func isRowCompletelyVisible(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let rect = rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        return boundsWithoutInset.contains(rect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:

> visibleCells Returns the table cells that are visible in the receiver.
>
> `- (NSArray *)visibleCells`
>
> Return Value An array containing UITableViewCell objects, each
> representing a visible cell in the
> receiving table view.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> See Also –
> indexPathsForVisibleRows

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear enough. I'm only interested in the cells which are completely visible. - (NSArray *)visibleCells and indexPathsForVisibleRows both return the cells which are completely visible and partly visible. As you can see in my code I am already using - (NSArray *)visibleCells to find the ones which are completely visible. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will let you check if a collection view cell is completely visible through the layout attributes of the collection view.

`guard let cellRect = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.frame else { return }
let isCellCompletelyVisible = collectionView.bounds.contains(cellRect)`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5+**

we can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       ...
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}


let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
```

Comment: didEndDisplaying could be called for cell before it became visible in a table view

Answer (score 0):

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
if (CGRectContainsRect(CGRectOffset(self.collectionView.frame, self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, self.collectionView.contentOffset.y), frame))
{
    // is on screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)checkVisibilityOfCell{
    if (tableView.contentSize.height <= tableView.frame.size.height) {
        return YES;
    } else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you said you want to check it every time you scrolled, you can also use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       CGRect cellRect = [tableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:tableView.superview];
       if (CGRectContainsRect(tableView.frame, cellRect)){
            //Do things in case cell is fully displayed
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for this issue better used next function from UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: This will not work. From a doc `tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the table.`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I was using `tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` to get the `UITableViewCell`'s frame, the height was coming as `0`

I ended up using this way :-

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    let cellFrame = cell.frame
    let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellFrame)
}
```