# How to handle UITableViewCell became not visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need release some resources when `UITableViewCell` became out of visible rect. `prepareForReuse` message is sent when `UITableViewCell` needs to be reused, but I need another... I have `UITableViewCell` subclass, and can override some messages...

This is exactly what I need: [tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidEndDisplayingCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)

But this is iOS6+ only solution. I need iOS4.3+ solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? If you're using cell reuse, your cell will be recycled, and you'll release your resources there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cell becomes hidden it is removed from the `UITableView`. So you can override in your `UITableViewCell` derived class method `willMoveToSuperview`:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
    NSLog(@"%p willMoveToSuperview: %p", self, newSuperview);
    if(newSuperview == nil) {
        // release some resources here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checked... This method get called only when cell became visible first time. So I see only 6 calls at all, it is size of my reuse pool.

Comment: `newSuperview` never became `nil`

Comment: Hm... I've just checked it in simulator and it seems working. I've added `NSLog` to the method and it proves the concept.

Comment: I have an idea. If you have so many cell to fill the whole screen, then the method `willMoveToSuperview` might not be called, since cell can be reused at the same moment without removing from table. Try to release resources in `prepareForReuse` too.

Comment: Hm.. I've double checked... `willMoveToSuperview` called every time.

Comment: I've solved my problem without subclassing - using `NSMutableDictionary` to connect cells and "userInfo". Anyway thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm not getting *any* calls to willMoveToSuperview in my UITableViewCell subclass (Swift 1.2, iOS8.4).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I need: [tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidEndDisplayingCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)

But this is iOS6+ only solution. I need iOS4.3+ solution.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`.

So one possible way should be to implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and check there which `UITableViewCell` is visible.

This should also help:
[Best way to check if UITableViewCell is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an else solved my problem. Where I reseted any changes that were made to the cell.

```
if (! self.cell) {
self.cell = [[LanguageCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
self.cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{ 
self.cell.checkImage.image = NO;

}
```