# iOS - How do apps like Path optimize their table cells where every cell is (almost) different?

Tags: ios, uitableview, path

So here's the issue i'm currently running into.

I have an app that shows a Facebook/Path like feed with a UITableView. Let's say that my datasource has about 200 items and not all cells have the same content and cell height. Some have images and some don't. I was able to overcome the scrolling performance issue by initializing my cells with a reusable identifier in the following format: [NSString stringWithFormat:"entry_%d", some_id]. Things were going really well up until I started using the UIImagePickerViewController. As you can imagine I've been receiving a lot of memory warnings due to my large datasource/table.

When playing with the Path's app and trying to load as many data into a single view; they do a really good job at both the scrolling performance and memory management. Their app also doesn't crash whenever I go into the camera mode.

Any thoughts or theories?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You're using a different reuse identifier for every cell?!

Comment: Yes :(. I couldn't find a way around it since almost every cell are unique. Scrolling performance has been improved even with 200+ cells. However, it's obviously a real hit in memory.

Comment: If it's just the layout that needs to change, just implement `-layoutSubviews`. You can additionally show/hide view for certain cells. It means labels will need to be redrawn, but it seems far better than simply not reusing cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you check out the Facebook iOS framework which reimplements the table view. The name of the framework is Three20, and you can find it on github [here](https://github.com/facebook/three20).

With that said, if you have a very large table, you need to be careful to only load resources for those things that are in view, and release resources for items once they go out of view. The delegate method `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` (available iOS 6 and later) is your friend for that. [Here is another question related to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible).