# UITableView scrolling performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-instruments

I am trying my best to profile my app using Instruments and find out where my code is expensive. The `[self checkVisibleCells]` method is called in `scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`. I get about two/three cells on screen, depending on their height.
I then determine if the cell is completely visible and mark it as read. Using the answer in this thread: [Best way to check if UITableViewCell is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

So far I can only see that `self.tableView.visibleCells` is taking a long time. Is it really THAT expensive to fetch `visibleCells`? Are there any better methods on how to do this?

Full size screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt8e2uat9t81qt3/Screenshot%202014-05-06%2009.26.25.png

[image: Time profiller]

Comment: Did you tried `willDisplayCell:` delegate method of `UITableView`?

Comment: It can happen that the cell that I want to `markAsRead` is not yet fully visible when other cellls call `willDisplaCell:`

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but isn't instruments telling you that 87% of the time spent in `checkVisibleCells` is spent on `self.tableView.visibleCells` which probably makes sense as there isn't much else going on in that method. The key might be how often you are calling `checkVisibleCells`? If its indicating that this method is taking up the most time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice than I can give you in this situation is to be sensible about when exactly you call `- (NSArray *)visibleCells` on the `tableView`.

`scrollViewDidScroll` gets called a hell of a lot. If you are then calling `.visibleCells` on the `tableView` every time, it is no wonder it is impacting your performance as much as it is.

My advice is that, considering you obviously know the height of your table view cells, (either declared in code or in IB), I would use this to your advantage. Note that this will not really work if your cells vary in height.

Up front, in your checkVisibleCells method, I would add this:

```
- (void)checkVisibleCells
{
    CGFloat newContentOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
    BOOL tableViewHasScrollFarEnough = newContentOffsetY > lastCheckedContentOffsetY + MysteriousViewControllerTableViewCellHeight;
    tableViewHasScrollFarEnough = tableViewHasScrollFarEnough || self.tableView.contentOffset.y < self.lastCheckedContentOffsetY - MysteriousViewControllerTableViewCellHeight;

    if (tableViewHasScrollFarEnough)
    {
        return;
    }

    self.lastCheckedContentOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;

    // ... the rest of the method
}
```

Comment: Significant change in performance with this little tweak. Thx.