# How do I play videos inline in a UICollectionView Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uicollectionview, inline

A UICollectionView will consist of a **feed** of videos. When the user is inline with a video, I would like it to play. With my current setup, several videos play at once (I suppose depending on the pagination) once they are loaded in to the collection view.

> How do I play videos inline in a UICollectionView?

A cell in the UICollectionView feed will contain a UIView, which will hold the video player. This is the UIView's class **PlayerViewClass**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
    
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
    
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The Feed's collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath delegate method in the **FeedViewController** is as follows:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
      if let cell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell {

      ...

      //Configuring the cell

      ...
    
      //Video player
      let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: post.fullURL)
        
      //Setting cell's player
      cell.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer
  
      //TODO: Change so this is only executed when the user is inline.
      cell.playerView.player?.play()
    
    }
    return cell
  }
```

The cell **MyCollectionViewCell** has an IBOutlet linked to the playerView UIView:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: PlayerViewClass!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib() 

   //Setup, not relevant

   }

}
```

I found the following [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ashish0309/AutoVideoPlayer), which shows the functionality that I would like to implement; however, I'm a little unsure of how to do this with my setup below.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to know which cells are visible.You get that "for free" via the `UICollectionView` API's `visibleCells` property. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells).

Additionally, you'll need to do some bookkeeping when the `UICollectionView` scrolls. In reviewing the documentation for `UICollectionView`, you'll see it is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` comes with delegate methods that enable you to track this. Here's a "physics for poets" approach to what you could do to accomplish this task:

Let's say this is your view controller:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Then, you'd implement your `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods here:

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // Bare bones implementation
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // TODO: need to implement
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // TODO: need to implem,ent
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Finally, you'd implement [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate#) methods to detect beginning of scrolling and end of scrolling. Here's where you'd implement your logic for starting/stopping video:

```
extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
            // TODO: write logic to stop the video before it begins scrolling
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
            // TODO: write logic to start the video after it ends scrolling
        }
    }
}
```

You'll want to muck around with the timing of stopping/starting animations to see what looks good, so feel free to poke around the various `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you so much! This is beyond helpful! I have a question: Is there a way to go about determining the video cell that is in the user's current view (or closest to the center of their view) so I can implement the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating and scrollViewWillBeginDragging methods?

Comment: Looking around, this seems to answer that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899689/swift-find-out-which-table-view-cell-occupies-most-of-screen

Comment: Agreed. However, (I forgot to mention), with my current layout constraints the view container will have at most two cells present at any given time.

Comment: You'd want to compare the center of the visible cells to either the UICollectionView's centers and determine which cell is closest. You'll want to compare CGPoints.

Answer (score 1):

For a play a video in Inline you can refer to the MMPlayerView in gitHub it will be a helpful framework "https://cocoapods.org/pods/MMPlayerView"