# Table view cell visibility

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using table view custom cell in my application in swift language.I am performing scaling animation for cell while scrolling up and down. I need to detect whether the cell is fully visible during my scrolling. Can any one help me out regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide information of what you have tried and where you are having troubles. Your question is just too broad.

Comment: I need to check whether cell at current indexpath is fully visible or not

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible

Comment: use *tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)* method to get cell rect and see complete rect is withing screen frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `visibleCells` property on UITableView, and check if your cell is there. Check out the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/visibleCells) for UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rect of a cell with rectForRowAtIndexPath: method and compare it with tableview's bounds rect using CGRectContainsRect function.

Note that this will not instantiate the cell if it is not visible, and thus will be rather fast.

```
let cellRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
```