# Handling loading efficiently while scrolling on a UICollectionView of Videos

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, user-experience

I am currently building an objective c application in xcode that features a full screen horizontally scrolling collection view with cells that take up about 80% of the screen; similar to that of Instagram, Vine, etc.  Initially in these cells are video thumbnails that are loaded from a backend source upon the loading of the view.

Since it would be terribly inefficient to load all of these videos at once, I am trying to find a way to only load one video at a time while the user scrolls through the collection view.

The way I am achieving this right now is by using the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method to calculate whichever cell is in the center of the screen after scrolling, and then beginning to load the video, as well as the `scrollViewDidScroll` method to stop loading the video.  This implementation is shown below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    //calculate which cell is in the center
    //load video in respective cell  

}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    //stop loading video

}
```

As you all can probably see, this generates a lot of ux problems:

1. The video doesn't start loading until scrolling has stopped
   completely
2. This approach doesn't account for drag gestures to
   navigate the Collection View
3. Once a video has loaded, any drag or
   scroll stops loading/playing the video
4. There are times where no video is loading, between scrolls

I am trying to turn this current approach into a system similar to the Instagram method of loading videos, which is as follows:

1. A video begins to load as soon as it begins to show up on the screen while the user scrolls
2. A video stops loading when a different video begins to appear on the screen while the user scrolls.
3. One video is always being loaded, there is no downtime between loading one video and another

I understand that in order to achieve this functionality, these loading functions will need to be done on a background thread in order to allow for seamless scrolling which I can handle, I just need to know which methods I should be using instead of the ones i'm using now in order to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Rather than trying to infer cell visibility based on scrolling you might want to check out `UICollectionViewDelegate`'s `willDisplay:` and `didEndDisplaying:` methods, if you haven't already. As the names suggest, these will tell you directly when you might want to kick off loading based on a cell being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should make it such that the video uses "lazy loading" to load its contents/thumbnail.
2. To make it play when cell is at center, use `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect if the cell is completely showing by method indicated at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9833241/501439)

Comment: I know how to make a video play when it is at the center and I know how to load its contents, I am trying to change the functionality to what I described in the second list.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, what you want in second list is simply lazyloading?