# How to determine when a custom UICollectionViewCell is 100% on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

From the diagram above I have `UICollectionView` with 4 custom cells.  At any time 2 or three cells can be on the screen.  How can I tell when "cell 1" or "cell 2" is 100% on the screen?

Both

```
collectionView.visibleCells
collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
```

return arrays and doesn't tell you if what cell 100% on the screen.

In the case of the image, the following will be display on `didSelectItemAt`

`collectionView.visibleCells`

```
[<Shot_On_Goal.MainCollectionViewCell: 0x101f525c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (190 7.66667; 454 350); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0237300>>, <Shot_On_Goal.HeaderCollectionViewCell: 0x101f4d580; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 0; 170 365); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0236800>>, <Shot_On_Goal.TheirHockeyNetCollectionViewCell: 0x101f55520; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (654 7.66667; 454 350); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0238fe0>>]
```

`collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems`

```
[[0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: Have you considered using [CGRectContainsRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454186-cgrectcontainsrect) ?

Comment: Looks like someone did this with a [tableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible) already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will return an Array of IndexPaths for the fully visible cells:

```
func fullyVisibleCells(_ inCollectionView: UICollectionView) -> [IndexPath] {

    var returnCells = [IndexPath]()

    var vCells = inCollectionView.visibleCells
    vCells = vCells.filter({ cell -> Bool in
        let cellRect = inCollectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: inCollectionView.superview)
        return inCollectionView.frame.contains(cellRect) 
    })

    vCells.forEach({
        if let pth = inCollectionView.indexPath(for: $0) {
            returnCells.append(pth)
        }
    })

    return returnCells

}

@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {

    let visCells = fullyVisibleCells(self.collectionView)
    print(visCells)

}
```

Comment: Where should this be called? Pressing button all the times seems quite absurd to me. I mean is there any way I can know as soon as my scrolling stops. ref : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53055965/4306200

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Why collectionView.superview and not just collectionView?

Comment: @LuchiParejoAlcazar - if you convert the cell frame to `collectionView`, the resulting `origin.x` will be relative to the collection view's content. So, if your cells are 100-pts wide, and you've scrolled so the left edge of the 10th cell is at the left edge of the view, `cellRect.origin.x` will be `900` (9 cells are off-screen)... using `collectionView.superview` converts it relative to the superview, so `cellRect.origin.x` will be `0`. Try it yourself... add some `print()` statements to see the results.

Comment: Does not work in case of UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. returns random values in array

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extension for it, based don DonMag's answer:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    var fullyVisibleCells : [UICollectionViewCell] {
        return self.visibleCells.filter { cell in
            let cellRect = self.convert(cell.frame, to: self.superview)
            return self.frame.contains(cellRect) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your visibleCells array to check if the frame of your cell is included in the frame of your collectionView:

```
    var visibleCells = self.collectionView?.visibleCells
    visibleCells = visibleCells?.filter({ cell -> Bool in
        return self.collectionView?.frame.contains(cell.frame) ?? false
    })
    print (visibleCells)
```