# Determine if image in table view cell is completely visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift5

I have a table view where each table view cell has an image.

I need to determine when an image view is completely visible on scroll. Additionally, if two images in two separate table view cells are completely visible at the same time, I want to only trigger an action for the first image.

I've thought of using [`willDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview), but I've found that this only ever triggers once and it triggers as soon as the cell comes into view.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible), but it's specific to determining if the table view cell itself is completely visible, rather than a view within a table view cell.

What are my options? What is the best way of going around this?

Comment: You can user
let cells = tableView.visibleCells

Comment: Set yourself as the scroll view delegate and examine the situation as scrolling takes place.

Comment: @matt I'm not quite sure what you mean. I did just find out about `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, so I now know when to trigger the calculation, but I'm still unsure of how to calculate whether or not the image is visible.

Comment: Well you know the frame of all cells and the bounds offset of the table view. So it is easy to know what is fully visible.

Comment: I think you have to set the images asynchronously on the image view  and in  the completion block you have to send notification to the main view and maintain a boolean value for the particular cell .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up view controller that manages image cells, here is a part of code for such controller, which is delegate of `UITableView`, that demos an approach of how to track becoming images visible. Hope it will be helpful.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.verifyImagesVisibility()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
    self.verifyImagesVisibility()
}

private func verifyImagesVisibility() {
    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
        if let imageView = cell.imageView {
            let visibleRect = self.tableView.bounds
            let imageRect = imageView.convert(imageView.bounds, to: tableView)

            imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0 // for test
            if visibleRect.contains(imageRect) {
                // do anything here for image completely shown
                imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // for test
            } else {
                // do anything here for image become partially hidden
                imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor // for test
            }
        }
    }
}
```