# indexPathsForVisibleRows alternatives

Tags: ios, uikit

indexPathsForVisibleRows returns indexpaths for barely visible rows (maybe 5 px is visible) which is obviously is no terribly useful to determine if you need to scroll.

Is there an alternative that does not return partially occluded rows?

Comment: [I think this is what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

Comment: can you share the demo UI of the view so that i can understand batter. Thankyou

Comment: @FahimParkar thank you, that's it, apparently I saw that answer long time ago cause there are my upvotes :-))))))) running in circles